# Dialogue with tasks script doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a script that controls dialogue and gives tasks to main character in Unity game. There is a list of tasks and according to number of variable in list, dialogue can be changed. If variable equals 1 main character got a task, 2 task done, 3 main character told to NPC that task is done.  When NPC collider is triggered dialogue image appears and player sees words of NPC and 2 buttons with possible answers. One button closes dialogue image, another moves dialogue further.

Problem is that I can not find the way how to make it work `(tasks\[0\] == 3)`. Because it does not change and dialogue loops. I tried to put it in different places but nothing has changed.

I am a beginner so there can be some stupid mistakes that I did not notice.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Dialogue : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject dialogue;
    [SerializeField] Text npcText;
    
    [SerializeField] List<Text> buttonText = new List<Text>();
    public DialogueBlock[] dialogueBlock;
    [SerializeField] public PlayerController playerController;

    int dialogueBlockPlace = 0;
    public List<int> tasks = new List<int>();
    [SerializeField] List<string> taskString = new List<string>(); 

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Player")
        {
            dialogue.SetActive(true);
            dialogueBlockPlace = 0;
            Answer(0);
        }
    }
    public void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Player")
        {
            dialogue.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private void Answer(int num)
    {
        npcText.text = dialogueBlock[num].npcText;
        buttonText[0].text = dialogueBlock[num].playerAnswer[0].Text;
        buttonText[1].text = dialogueBlock[num].playerAnswer[1].Text;
    }
    
    public void AnswerButtonClicked(int buttonNum)//u=mesti ant mygtuko
    {
        if(dialogueBlock[dialogueBlockPlace].playerAnswer[buttonNum].speakEnd)
        {
            dialogue.SetActive(false);
        }
        dialogueBlockPlace = dialogueBlock[dialogueBlockPlace].playerAnswer[buttonNum].toBlock;
        TaskStarted();
        if (dialogueBlock[dialogueBlockPlace].playerAnswer[buttonNum].questInt == 1)
        {
            if (tasks[0] == 0)
            {
                tasks[0] = 1;
            }
            else if (tasks[0] > 2)
            {
                tasks[1] = 1;
            }
            else if (tasks[1] > 2 )
            {
                tasks[2] = 1;
            }
        }
        
        DialogueControl();
        
    }

    public void DialogueControl()
    {
        TaskDone();
        ChangeText();
        print(dialogueBlockPlace);
        Answer(dialogueBlockPlace);
    }

    private void TaskStarted()
    {
        if (tasks[0] == 1 || tasks[1] == 1 || tasks[2] == 1)
        {
            
            dialogueBlockPlace = 4;
        }
    }
    

    private void TaskDone()
    {
        if (tasks[0] == 2 || tasks[1] == 2 || tasks[2] == 2)
        {
            
            dialogueBlockPlace = 3;
            tasks[0] = 3;//dont work

        }
    }
    
    public void ChangeText()
    {
        if (tasks[0]==0)
        {
            dialogueBlock[2].npcText = taskString[0];
        }
        if (tasks[0] == 3)
        {
            dialogueBlock[2].npcText = taskString[1];
        }
        if (tasks[1] == 3)
        {
            dialogueBlock[2].npcText = taskString[2];
        }

    }
}
[System.Serializable]
public class DialogueBlock
{
    public string npcText;
    public PlayerAnswer[] playerAnswer;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerAnswer
{
    public string Text;
    public int toBlock;
    public bool speakEnd;
    public int questInt;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoding state with an integer was OK 40 years ago, but is kida bad practice nowadays, since we have all these pesky objects, programming paradigms and smart patterns. Essentially what you're missing here is at least two classes and enum to properly name things and encapsulate them:

```
class Objective
{
    bool IsCompleted {get;}
    //...
}

class Quest
{
    enum QuestState
    {
        NotStarted,
        Started,
        Completed,
        RewardCollected
    }
    //...
    QuestState State {get;}
    Objective[] Objectives {get;}
}
```

Build your control flow with objects, extract behaviors from your code, isolate them in methods, and if method needs to handle complex state, it could easily be an objects on its own. Just in Unity don't put everything in its own MonoBehavior, you could use regular classes, especially for the lifetime-services:

```
class Unit : MonoBehaviour
{
    // use interface or base class to swap implementations easily
    protected IMovementBehaviour movementBehaviour {get;} 
    protected IAttackerBehaviour attackBehaviour {get;}
    protected IDialogueProvider dialogueProvider {get;}
    //...
}

class Villager : Unit
{
    //...
    void Awake()
    {
        movementBehaviour = new GroundMovement(); // assign 
        attackBehaviour = new MeleeAtacker();
        dialogueProvider  = new VillagerDialogue();
    }
}
```

Of course its just a rough illustration and you would rather use cozy ScriptableObjects to store different behaviour implementations, but you've got the point.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didnt know about this way of coding.